# What is and where is story of Ahobila Nava Narasimhas found?

Tags: puranas, temple, narasimha

There are 9 deities of Narasimha in [Ahobilam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahobilam).

What is the story of each Narasimha and name of each deity? Is Ahobila kshetra described in any puranas?